# How to reactivate the numbering of sections

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, titlesec

I used an older preamble of mine in which I turned off the numbering of sections on the particular pages and in the Table of Contents. Now, I am using it for another document, but I cannot reactivate it? Where is my mistake?

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Eingabekodierung: UTF-8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % ordentliche Trennung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=4cm,headheight=14.5pt,footnotesep=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[markcase=ignoreupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark[section]{section}



\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\thesection}{14pt}{\large}

\titleformat{\subsection}[display]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\thesubsection}{14pt}{\large}


\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]    {\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftbeforetoctitleskip{24pt}
\renewcommand\cftaftertoctitleskip{12pt}
\renewcommand\cftbeforeloftitleskip{24pt}
\renewcommand\cftafterloftitleskip{12pt}
\renewcommand\cftbeforelottitleskip{24pt}
\renewcommand\cftafterlottitleskip{12pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

%\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{section}} 
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
\large\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Section}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no `\chapter` in your MWE. So the section is numbered with `0.1` in the resulting pdf. Note that package `titlesec` should not be used together with a KOMA-Script class. What is the desired result?

Comment: The desired result is to re-activate the counting for chapters, sections, subsections with Roman uppercase numbers (e. g. II.I. et.). I changed from scrrprt to scrartcl as a document class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggestion with class `scrartcl` (as mentioned in your comment to the question) but without packages `titlesec` and `tocloft`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <- use utf8 instead utf8x
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[
  top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,
  left=2.5cm,right=4cm,
  headheight=14.5pt,footnotesep=1cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles % no contents in page header and footer??

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  font=\large,
  toclinefill=\hfill
]{section,subsection}

% Roman numbers for sections and subsections
\renewcommand*\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}

% Section and subsection numbers in an extra line
\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\thesection\autodot\\*[14pt]}
\renewcommand*\subsectionformat{\thesubsection\autodot\\*[14pt]}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}
    {#3#4}
    {\ifstr{#1}{subsection}
      {#3#4}
      {\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}% original definition for other section levels
    }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A Subsection}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want to change the sep before and after the headings in TOC and lists, you can add

```
\BeforeTOCHead{%
  \vspace*{24pt}%
}
\AfterTOCHead{%
  \addvspace{12pt}%
}
```

to the preamble.